# What is the best way, to get the properties and the name of three files, present in three separate folders, on a SharePoint online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, path, excel-online

I am recently experimenting with Microsoft Power Automate a lot and I am trying to tackle the following problem.

Let's imagine that you are present in a SharePoint online folder, and in this folder you have three separate folders each of which contains a  file of your interest.

What is the best way to get the name and path of that file using PowerAutomate?

The name and path of the file should later be inserted into a relevant Excel file using Power Automate.

I attach the screenshots describing my problem below.

1.Here is a screenshot of my whole site in which three folders with the names of:
Folder1,Folder2, Folder3 are the ones which are of my interest.

1.[image]

2.On the slide below I attach what the content of the folders looks like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

3.Next I would like to show my attempt when tackling the problem.

[image]
[image]

4.Next I  would like to show the Excel file in which the data should be stored.

[image]

The data from the Excel files should be stored in columns 1 and 2.(Name and Path).

If any of you knows the answer to the question, I would be grateful if you shared your solution with me.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, are the folder1, 2 and 3 static and are the 3 files also static? I think the solution will depend on these facts.

Comment: Yes, the files and the folders are static. The problem here is that I would need to derive the name of the folder as well as the name of the files using a PowerAutomate function. I have no idea which one to use though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "Full Path" property in "Add a row into a table".

[image]

My test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps and answers my question. I am therefore closing this thread, as the problem is now solved,